# How can I download the most recent uploaded file from the django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to create a efficient way to download the most recently uploaded file from the django admin. The idea is that every month or so, I go in the django admin and upload a excel file. That file will later be downloaded using a button (easy stuff). But what I have now (which isn't efficient), is that every month I upload a file and change the path from the button. This requires understanding of basic html and django, which my users wont understand. To summarize the idea, here is a list:

- Upload a file every month or so
- Have the button in html download the most recent file added (automatically)

I have thought of many things, like for example having a timestamp set when uploading the file, and have the button download the file with the most recent "date created". But, I couldn't get that to work, and even if I did, would that be an easy/recommended way of doing this? I have also thought of the ability for one to rename the file, but again, you'd need to have a basic understanding of the django admin, which isn't what I want my users to have to do.

Is there anything I could do? Any help is very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm guessing you are saving the files in a model.
What if you used the **File.objects.latest('id')** command?
This will give you the file that was uploaded most recently. You can then pass that to your html button. This saves you having to update the path each time.

models.py

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    actual_file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    # Store most recent uploaded file    
    file = File.objects.latest('id')  
    # Store file name (Whatever you called it inside your db)
    file_name = file.name
    actual_file = file.actual_file
    return render(request, "website/index.html", {   
        "file": actual_file,
        "name": file_name
    })
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="media/{{file}}" download> Download </a>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. Im having a bit of trouble at the moment, but I'm sure this is the way to do it. Imma mark it correct when I get it to work!

Comment: Great. Let me know if you need some more help 

Comment: Hey again. Im getting the error: "OperationalError at /
no such column: pages_files.name", and it points to this line: "file = File.objects.latest('id')". Do I have to import something in the html?

Comment: Make sure to create a file in the django admin first. Have you set up the root folder?

Comment: Hey, I had a little bit of trouble and later realized (as you said), I didn't upload a file with the appropriate name. I have done that and im now attempting to identify another issue. But yea, thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, I got it to spit out no errors, but, when I upload 2 files, it doesn't download the latest. Could this have to do with the random string of characters django adds to files when uploaded? For example: I upload a file "excel" and upload another file named "excel", django changes the second file name to be somthing like "excel11k23hk".

Comment: BTW, I had to modify the line "name = models.CharField(max_length=64)" to "name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='' )" for it to produce no errors (just adding the default=). Is this something bad?

Comment: Okay, I modified the main code so now it will download the correct file no matter what you set the File.name to. Let me know how it goes. Check the main comment above :) I edited the html and views file.

Comment: Yes! It is downloading the latest file. I keep uploading a newer file and it automatically updates. But, it downloads a file with the error Error: No file was found (referring to the name). This is the correct answer though. I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Okay I now understand what you mean. Django seems to be adding random characters to avoid multiple files with same name. Do you need the previous files to stored? Or can you delete them from memory?

Comment: I think it would be better if I just delete it. I always keep a backup in my external hard drive so I should probably just delete the previously most recent file (basically just what you said).

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. I was trying to download my file from the path: "media/uploads/files/uploads/files/excelmodified.xlsx". So as you can see, I just messed up with the path thing. So yeah, thanks for your help! You got this to work!

Comment: Good job! Glad I could help.